# Inherit template blocks from parent of parent in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've 3 template files named `**base.html**`, `**navbar.html**` and `**dashboard.html**`.

`base.html` is the main parent file which has a `**{% block content %}**`.

Navbar has `**{% block navtitle %}**`.

Now What I want to do is, I want `**navtitle**` block in my `'dashboard.html'` file.

Both `navbar.html` and `dashboard.html` extends `**base.html**`. I'm able to get `**content**` block from `base.html` file, but can't get **navbar** block.

Please guide me how can I do the same

Sample files below

**base.html**

```html
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
```

**navbar.html**

```html
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block navtitle %} {% endblock %}
```

**dashboard.html**

```html
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %} Demo {% endblock %}          # Able to print it
    {% block navtitle %} Demo 2 {% endblock %}       # Not able to print it
```

I also tried to extend navbar.html file in dashboard.html file but still no luck.

Comment: did you try the `include`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include

Comment: That's now how this works, when you `extend base` you're taking the base.html template and its blocks. Your navbar.html should not extend base.html as it is not supposed to be a full web page. Then `{% include navbar.html %}` in base.html, that way every page extending base will have the nav bar and can override any of its blocks.

Comment: @dirkgroten tried that way also, but not working

Comment: @Jack of course it works, you did it wrong. Please update your question with what you did. Again, base.html should contain all the blocks, either directly in base.html or via includes. Any template extending base.html can only use blocks that it inherits from base.html, any other block won't be rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Inheritance (1/2)**

base.html

```
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
{% block navtitle %} {% endblock %}
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %} Demo {% endblock %}
{% block navtitle %} Demo 2 {% endblock %}
```

**Using Inheritance (2/2)**

*useful when some templates will only inherit from `base.html` while others will inherit from `navbar.html`*

base.html

```
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
{% block navtitle %} {% endblock %}
```

navbar.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block navtitle %} {% endblock %}
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}
{% block content %} Demo {% endblock %}
{% block navtitle %} Demo 2 {% endblock %}
```

**Using include**

base.html

```
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
{% include "path/to/navbar.html" %}
```

navbar.html

```html
<div>Some html</div>
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %} Demo {% endblock %}
{% block navtitle %} Demo 2 {% endblock %}
```

Checkout django's templates documentation for [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include) and [inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)